# Magento: how to add new helper and block to module that exists?

Tags: xml, magento

I would like to add own helper and block to catalog module.

I don't understand enough this part.

I've added Company_Catalog.xml to Modules xml folder and created files:

```
code/local/Company/Catalog/Helper/ResizeImage.php
code/local/Company/Catalog/Block/ResizeImage.php
code/local/Company/Catalog/etc/config.xml
```

**code/local/Company/Catalog/etc/config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <resizeimage>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Catalog</module>
                    <frontName>resizeimage</frontName>
                </args>
            </resizeimage>
        </routers>
     </frontend>
     <global>
        <blocks>
            <resizeimage>
                <class>Company_Catalog_Block</class>
            </resizeimage>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <resizeimage>
               <class>Company_Catalog_Helper</class>
            </resizeimage>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**code/local/Company/Catalog/Helper/ResizeImage.php:**

```
class Company_Catalog_Helper_ResizeImage extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
   //.....
}
```

**code/local/Company/Catalog/Block/ResizeImage.php:**

```
class Company_Catalog_Block_ResizeImage extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
   //.......
}
```

So nothing happens if I call some block method. It seems I'm doing smth wrong in a config.xml.

PS: Could someone to recommend some links about config.xml which are more detailed then here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference?/module_config.xml

### UPDATE:

I call it in template like `$this->helper('catalog/resizeimage');` and after I changed capitalisation I get this error (before I didn't):

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Helper_ResizeImage' not found in ..... app/Mage.php on line 516
```

Comment: The folders should have the same capitalisation as the class names, so use `app/code/local/Company/Catalog/`. This depends on the underlying filesystem which means unix-types are affected by case and windows generally are not.

Comment: how do you use the methods? except for the capitalization, it looks right

Comment: Thanks, guys! Unfortunately I got error. Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

As a starting point, I think the Helper problem is that you should be accessing a method in the Helper/Data.php file of your module.